# rename mvc model object in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 and usually Visual Studio will create all the views for you. I have one form that just has one field and I want to just embed the create form into the Index View.

So the Index View has something like `@model IEnumerable<Models.LinkModel>`

So I access it by iterating through the Model collection.

But if I try to embed the form for the create action I need `@model Models.LinkModel` 
and it is accessed by Model.Name as well. Is there a way to do this or use a different variable name?

**Ok here is some extra info.**

SO I have a model.

```
public class LinkModel
{
   public string LinkUrl {get;set;}
}
```

I have a controller that has the Create and Index ActionResults.

Now in the Index view I have

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.LinkModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Links";
}
```

I can do all my fancy logic to list all the links.

```
@foreach(link in Model)
{
    <p>link.LinkUrl<p>
}
```

The Create View has this

```
@model Models.LinkModel // Note that it is just one item not IEnumerable

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Link";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset class="editor-fieldset">
        <legend>LinkModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LinkUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LinkUrl)
        </div>
       <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Link" />
       </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Now it seems pretty stupid to have a create form for just one field. I want to put this form on the Index page. Problem is that I access the object using the variable Model. I wanted to know if there is a way to have two seperate instances or be able to access the Model objects with different names.

Comment: I really have no idea what you're asking here.  You need to clarify your thoughts and explain what you want in better detail.

Comment: Why is it this closed? I added the extra info?

Comment: Because your question still doesn't make any sense.  We don't know what you mean by "a way to have two seperate instances or be able to access the Model objects with different names".

Comment: Because you didn't get it? The accepted answer was able to get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a composite model with a list of items and 1 single item for the create

```
public class  IndexModel {
   public LinkModel CreateModel {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<LinkModel> Items {get; set;}
}


@model IndexModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("create")) {
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CreateModel.Name);
}
@foreach(var item in Model.Items) {
  @item.Name
}
```

Comment: I think I'm just missing something small. I got the index to show the Items but when I create it just returns the Index view and doesn't hit my create Action. I checked in Fiddler and it is just posting /Link/Index when I hit submit.

Comment: what does your BeginForm call look like? it should have "Create" as the first argument

Comment: Yes that was it I needed parameters in the BeginForm("Create","LinkControllerName") Thanks a lot for the help.